# What would be the payload for publishing Post Telemetry message to Kafka Topic - Protocol message parsing fails

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, rule-engine, thingsboard

Post Telemetry message is posted to Kafka Topic, Rule engine fails while parsing the Telemetry message. What would be the payload for Post Telemetry message?

We simulated the scenario by publishing the Post Telemetry message to Kafka topic from Rule Engine using Kafka Node. But while the rule engine parses back the post telemetry message from kafka topic it throws the following error

```
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length

2019-04-05 18:37:06,455 [Akka-rule-dispatcher-71] DEBUG o.t.s.a.ruleChain.RuleChainActor - Processing msg: RuleNodeToRuleChainTellNextMsg(originator=30454c20-5560-11e9-8a39-513b18f007c6, relationTypes=[Success], msg=TbMsg(id=d031d960-57d1-11e9-af3f-ad9edc414a87, type=POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST, originator=46b20440-555a-11e9-9049-e5861a1c8c53, metaData=TbMsgMetaData(data={deviceType=default, offset=2, userName=tenant@thingsboard.org, userId=4642a0a0-555a-11e9-9049-e5861a1c8c53, deviceName=Test Device A1, partition=2, scope=SERVER_SCOPE, topic=tb.rule-engine, ts=1554489426443}), dataType=JSON, data={"Temperature":"99"}, transactionData=TbMsgTransactionData(transactionId=d031d960-57d1-11e9-af3f-ad9edc414a87, originatorId=46b20440-555a-11e9-9049-e5861a1c8c53), ruleChainId=461a3110-555a-11e9-9049-e5861a1c8c53, ruleNodeId=null, clusterPartition=0))
2019-04-05 18:37:06,455 [Akka-rule-dispatcher-71] TRACE o.t.s.a.r.RuleChainActorMessageProcessor - [45f9b0c0-555a-11e9-9049-e5861a1c8c53][30149f30-5560-11e9-8a39-513b18f007c6][d031d960-57d1-11e9-af3f-ad9edc414a87] No outbound relations to process
2019-04-05 18:37:06,456 [pool-9-thread-1] TRACE o.t.s.s.t.RemoteRuleEngineTransportService - Processing 1 records
2019-04-05 18:37:06,456 [pool-9-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.s.t.RemoteRuleEngineTransportService - Failed to process the notification.
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:82)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipRawBytesSlowPath(CodedInputStream.java:1284)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipRawBytes(CodedInputStream.java:1267)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:187)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipMessage(CodedInputStream.java:263)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.skipField(CodedInputStream.java:190)
        at org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos$ToRuleEngineMsg.<init>(TransportProtos.java:22821)
        at org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos$ToRuleEngineMsg.<init>(TransportProtos.java:22790)
        at org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos$ToRuleEngineMsg$1.parsePartialFrom(TransportProtos.java:23316)
        at org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos$ToRuleEngineMsg$1.parsePartialFrom(TransportProtos.java:23311)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:139)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:173)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:190)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49)
        at org.thingsboard.server.gen.transport.TransportProtos$ToRuleEngineMsg.parseFrom(TransportProtos.java:22962)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.transport.ToRuleEngineMsgDecoder.decode(ToRuleEngineMsgDecoder.java:29)
        at org.thingsboard.server.service.transport.To

19-04-05 18:37:06,456 [pool-9-thread-1] WARN  o.t.s.s.t.RemoteRuleEngineTransportService - Failed to process the notification.
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
        at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:82)
```

This is the script i used to send the payload to Kafka

```
enter code here 
var ms = Date.now();
msg = { "Temperature" :"99" };
msgType = "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST";
metadata.deviceType = "default";
metadata.deviceName = "Test Device A1";
metadata.ts=ms;
return { msg: msg,metadata: metadata,msgType: msgType };
```

Comment: Based on the error, you byte-array payload seems not to match the protobuf schema you are expecting... There could be many reasons this happens, but a common one is that anybody could just throw random data into a topic.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  This is the script in rule chain ,which is used to send payload var ms = Date.now();
 msg = { "Temperature" :"99" };
 msgType = "POST_TELEMETRY_REQUEST";
 metadata.deviceType = "default";
 metadata.deviceName = "Test Device A1";
 metadata.ts=ms;
 return {
     msg: msg,
     metadata: metadata,
     msgType: msgType
 };  what i might be missing in the protobuf schema

Comment: We would need to see the protobuf schema to really know that